# HTML CSS h3 iframe positioning

Tags: html, css, iframe, position, title

I have an h3 tag, a paragraph and the facebook iframe Like button.

```
 <h3>Spread out the word</h3>

<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:90px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

<p class="txtlike">Like us on Facebook</p>
```

How would I be able to set the CSS so the like button is next to h3 tag (in the same row) and has full width possible so the button can expand (some different languages extend the button). The only way I have found that it works is to just put the iframe inside h3 and I know that is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

```
h3{
  display: inline-block;
  /*or...*/
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had some hard times but I was able to do it with ´inline-block´ in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use following in your css. Hope it helps

```
h3
{
    width:25%;  
    float:left; 
}
iframe 
{
  width:75%;
}
```

change width accordingly.